# Create a lookup field in custom HTML pop up

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a custom HTML pop up and i would like to have a lookup field to the account entity, one that works like it would on a regular form.

Is this possible? If so how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom HTML can't have a lookup field, because lookup field isn't a HTML component. However, what you might do is ti create a set of controls that all together look and behave like the lookup. (In fact, that's how it's done in CRM too - one just never sees that happen.)

It's quirky and not smooth at all to do that so you might consider either resolving it with a field that isn't exactly a lookup (but sort-of behaving like one) or skipping the custom HTML and working with the standard forms.